# How to remove a single quote from a string in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle

i am trying to clean my data and i want to remove a single quote from the strings.

i have already used the function

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(recp_co_nm_clean,'[^'' ''[:alpha:]'' '']'
```

but even after this the text still contains single quotes.

for eg

```
INT'L
```

or

```
X'94343413
```

the output should be 
INTL
or
X94343413.

Comment: Are single quote characters considered "unclean"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
REPLACE(recp_co_nm_clean,chr(39),'')
```

Answer (score 4):

For your examples, you can just use `replace()`:

```
replace(recp_co_nm_clean, '''', '')
```

Comment: you know what they say: *I had a problem I thought I could solve with regex. Now I have two problems.*